# Cant Upload a CSV File in jupyter using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried

```
def loadCsv(filename):   
 lines=csv.reader(open(r'D:xxxivateNLPSearchingMaterialImplementationprojectpid.csv'))
```

it gives

```
 IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

2nd I try

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir('D:\mxxx\NLP\SearchingMaterial\Implementation\project')
df = pd.read_csv('pid.csv')
print(df)
```

it gives

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: malformed \N character escape
```

Answer (score 1):

This can occur with windows paths as the default directory includes backslash `\` in the path and when python loads it as a string, we get a *unicodeescape* error as `\u` is a unicode escape in python. In order to make it work, you have to use two backslashes

`'D:\\mxxx\\NLP\\SearchingMaterial\\Implementation\\project'`